# Not to wait for a certain command to end execution;

Tags: bash, shell

I have a little script to run a search daemon, like:
`run.sh`:

```
cd ~/apache-solr
xterm -e java -jar start.jar
sleep 5
cd ~/anotherFolder
#make something else
```

The problem:
  - after the `xterm -e ...` command the script waits for the command is complete to run another commands;

The question:
Can we run next command without waiting for the end of `xterm -e ...` command executing?

*P.S.*
Sorry for my English and Thanks for any help.

Comment: background task -by running command with & at the end

Comment: @Jayan you should copy that to a answer. Thank you.

Comment: It helps  you spend sometime in understanding the shell : there are material online.. like http://writers.fultus.com/garrels/ebooks/Machtelt_Garrels_Bash_Guide_for_Beginners_2nd_Ed.pdf

Comment: Wow. I'd wish to get such a rapid answers to every question. Thanks ^_^

Comment: there are already answers below, accept one (and probably upvote some)

Comment: @Jayan i wanted to accept yours as you were the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or even better you could use `nohup`

Like:

```
nohup xterm -e java -jar start.jar &
```

With nohup your command will not receive a killsig even if you close your putty session for example.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. Gonna mark your answer as correct because you've told about 'nohup' :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can put an `&` after your line you want to run in the background; that will allow your script to continue while the command is running;

```
xterm -e java -jar start.jar &
```

An example;

```
date
sleep 5
date

> Thu Mar 22 11:57:17 CET 2012
> Thu Mar 22 11:57:22 CET 2012

date
sleep 5 &
date

> Thu Mar 22 11:57:25 CET 2012
> Thu Mar 22 11:57:25 CET 2012
```

Answer (score 1):

yes put `&` at end of command, that will start new thread of execution

Answer (score 1):

An ampersand at the end of a command will start the command in the background and let the script continue with the next line.

```
 xterm -e java -jar start.jar &
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
xterm -e java -jar start.jar &
```

Note the ending `&` that tells the shell to run the process in the background.

It is another question how to know when that command finished if you need the results in your script.